# Как решить задачу ?(на биты)

Tags: c++

[image: Задача]

Надо решить данную задачу. Я пытался это сделать своими знаниями, но не получилось.
(Снизу будет макет кода) Что надо добавить, чтобы задача решалась?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
int main()
{
    long long a;
    int k;
    std::cin >> a >> k;
    int c;
    std::cin >> c;
    if (c == 1) {
        std::bitset <64> A(a);
        int x = A.size();
        A.reset(x - k); //я думал надо выесть чтобы получить числа ДО
        a = A.to_ullong();
        std::cout << a;
    }
    else if (c == 2) {
        std::bitset <64> A(a);
        int x = A.size();
        A.flip(k);// я думал инвертировать, НО что то не так.
        a = A.to_ullong();
        std::cout << a;
    }
    else if (c == 3) {
        std::bitset <64> A(a);
        int x = A.size();
        A.reset(...); // здесь вообще не понимаю
        a = A.to_ullong();
        std::cout << a;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> обнулите все биты числа a до k не включительно

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) a &= ~(1 << i);
```

> инвертируйте k-ый бит числа a

```
a ^= (1 << k);
```

> обнулите все биты числа a начиная с k-ого

```
for (std::size_t i = k; i < 32; ++i) a &= ~(1 << i);
```

Comment: Для обнуления подряд идущих битов лучше использовать не цикл, а сделать маску. `(1 << k) - 1` -- маска, где все биты младше k  равны 1 (она сразу годится для последнего случая, а для первого подойдет ее инверсия)

Comment: @avp, полностью согласен. Но когда подумал об этом, был уже дан другой ответ, где так и было сделано. Так что оставил, как есть :)

Comment: C учётом того, что переменная `a` имеет тип `long long` (по крайней мере 64-битный), а литерал `1` имеет тип `int` (обычно 32-битный), то результат выражения `a ^= (1 << k);` при `a == 0` и `k == 31` скорее всего [будет неверен](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6b04b19668b9500).

Comment: @wololo, я, честно говоря, на это вообще не обратил внимания. Исходя из условий задачи я бы выбрал std::uint32_t.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант реализации:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long a;
    int k, с;
    
    std::cin >> a >> k;
    std::cin >> c;

    if (c == 1) {
        a &= ( (unsigned long)-1 >> (32-k));
    }
    else if (c == 2) {
        a ^= (1 << k);
    }
    else if (c == 3) {
        a &= ( (unsigned long)-1 << k);
    }
    std::cout << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: 1) Первый случай обнуляет биты _включая_ `k`-тый бит. 2) Если тип `unsigned long` — 32-битный, и `k` равно `0`, то происходит сдвиг 32-битного целого на 32 бита, что вызывает неопределённое поведение. 3) Если тип `unsigned long` 64-битный, то обнуления 32-битного значения из переменной `a` вообще не происходит. 4) Третий пример обнуляет биты _не включая_ `k`-тый бит.