# Помогите упростить код C++

Tags: c++

У меня есть рабочий код, но он СЛИШКОМ долго ДУМАЕТ , из-за чего не подходит под некоторые решения. Как ускорить выполнение этого кода программы, не меняя его существенно(чтобы он делал тоже самое что и сейчас, НО быстрее).Исполнение одного запроса около 4 секунды, я его сузил до 0.5 секунды, а желательно до 0.01 с

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <bitset>
 int main()
 {
     long long a;
     int k;
     std::cin >> a >> k;
     int c;
     std::cin >> c;
     if (c == 1) {
         for (std::size_t i = 0; i < k; +i) a &= ~(static_cast <long long>(1) << i);
         std::cout << a;
     }
     else if (c == 2) {
         a ^= (static_cast <long long>(1) << k);
         std::cout << a;
     }
     else if (c == 3) {
         a = (static_cast <long long>(1) << k) - 1;
         std::cout << a;
     }
 }
```

Comment: опишите в вопросе что ваш код должен делать.

Comment: А что ваш код *должен делать*? Оптимизация начинается всегда с алгоритма... Но рекомендую для начала  в цикле `for (std::size_t i = 0; i < k; +i)` добавить еще один плюсик к `+i`, думаю, это поможет немного...

Comment: Не то чтобы это повлияет на скорость, но имеет смысл использовать `ll` литералы вместо кастов и добавить хедер для `std::size_t`.

Comment: А чем Вам эти варианты не приглянулись? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1466149/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b/1466167#1466167

Comment: Они не правильные, для некоторых исключительных решений

Comment: @Alex219XR Каких? И Вы считаете, что вариант 3 - a = (static_cast <long long>(1) << k) - 1;  корректный?

Comment: Всё время уходит на запуск и завершение процесса. Думайте как обойтись без этого. Например, сделать что-то вроде сервера.

Answer (score 1):

```
long long a,
    b{ 1 };      
unsigned k, c;
std::cin >> a >> k >> c;
b <<= k;    

switch (c)
{
case 1:
    a &= b - 1;
     break;
case 2:
    a ^= b;
    break;
default:
    a = b - 1;       
}
cout << a;
```