# Ошибка в коде , не все значения подходят (с++)

Tags: c++

Код пишет ошибку. Весь день ее ищу. Не все числа проходят правильно его решения.
//a = 0 ≤ a < 2^32
//k = 0 ≤ k < 32)

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    long long a;
    int k;
    std::cin >> a >> k;
    unsigned int c;
    std::cin >> c;
    switch (c) {
    case 1:
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) a &= ~(1 << i); //надо обнулить все биты 
числа а до k-ого не включительно 
    std::cout << a;
        break;
    case 2:
        a ^= (1 << k);  std::cout << a; // надо инвертировать k-ый бит числа a 
        break;
    case 3:
        for (std::size_t i = k; i < 32; ++i) a &= ~(1 << i); // надо обнулить все биты 
числа а начиная с k-ого 
    std::cout << a;
    }
return 0;
}
```

(извините что так много вопросов по этому коду)

Comment: Зачем плодите вопросы по одной проблеме? Вам ответили в первой же ветке

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как решить задачу ?(на биты)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1466149/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b)

Comment: ТОТ код неправильный

Comment: Тогда приведите пример, на котором он неверно работает.

Comment: 2^32 - это unsigned long, а long long - int64

Answer (score 2):

Давайте уже закроем эту тему...

```
void doit(unsigned long a, unsigned long  k, int c)
{
    unsigned long mask = (unsigned long )-1;
    mask >>= 32 - k;
    switch(c)
    {
    case 1: a = a & ~mask; break;
    case 2: a = a ^ (mask+1); break;
    case 3: a = a & mask;  break;
    }
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Если хочется вычислять `mask` через цикл, то вместо

```
    unsigned long mask = (unsigned long )-1;
    mask >>= 32 - k;
```

пишем

```
unsigned long mask = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i) mask = (mask << 1)|1;
```

Comment: Если тип `unsigned long` 32-битный, и `k == 0`, то происходит сдвиг 32-битной переменной на 32 бита, что вызывает неопределённое поведение. Если тип `unsigned long` 64-битный, то программа работает неверно. Например, в третьем случае не происходит обнуление битов 32-битного значения из переменной `a`.

Comment: @wololo OK, обновил ответ... Хотя из условия `k = 0 ≤ k < 32` как бы намекает...

Comment: `Хотя из условия k = 0 ≤ k < 32 как бы намекает...` На что намекает? `Заменить 32 на sizeof(unfigned long)*8` Теперь, при `k == 0` поведение программы не определено независимо от битности типа `unsigned long`.

Comment: @wololo Жаль, что ответ уже принят и я не могу просто его удалить. Чем еще могу помочь?